# Terraform google_proejct_iam_member giving Error 400: Policy members must be of the form "<type>:<value>"., badRequest

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create an IAM resource in GCP to assign a custom role to a service account.

The terraform code is given below.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "basic_role_permissions" {
  project = "${var.project}"
  role    = "projects/${var.project}/roles/${google_project_iam_custom_role.basic_role.role_id}"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.falcon.email}"
}
```

While deploying this I'm getting following error

```
 Batch "iam-project-PROJECT-ID modifyIamPolicy" for request "Create IAM Members projects/PROJECT-ID/roles/test_CloudSqlClient serviceAccount:test@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com for \"project \\\"PROJECT-ID\\\"\"" returned error: Error applying IAM policy for project "PROJECT-ID": Error setting IAM policy for project "PROJECT-ID": googleapi: Error 400: Policy members must be of the form "<type>:<value>"., badRequest
```

Following is the version information

**Terraform** : 0.12.20

**google Provider** : ~> 3.0.0

**google-beta Provider** : ~> 3.0.0

I can see the member string is of correct format `<type>:<member>` and yet Terraform is complaining.

Comment: I know it could be a silly question but could you please confirm the SA test@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com is not deleted?

Comment: @Pejvak Yes I can confirm that its not deleted. That SA is also getting crated as part of the same terraform module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a possible workaround [here](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/issues/380#issuecomment-564728413) please try pinning your provider version to 2.12.0 and check if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this myself (we're still using google provider v3.2.0 at work).

The bug is https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/5151 (fixed in 2.20.1/3.3.0).

An easy fix is to search on https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam for `"deleted"` and manually remove the members that start with `deleted:` (if there's a deleted member in *any* role at the project level, this bug affects you).

For more details on the underlying issue, see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/iam_deleted_members